# Roman Blinds Installation

Tags: blinds, curtain-rail

[image]

Hi, I have bought these curtains, but received no screws with them.

I have been told they can be mounted directly on the window.

What kind of screw head do I need for this to fit to it?

The window is PVC.

Comment: what do the installation instructions say?

Comment: there aren't any, it's some custom made I guess. seems similar to what Ive seen on youtube, except that click system

Comment: is the small plastic square used for mounting the curtain rail?

Comment: yes, I don't see any other option than that. But don't know to what it would fit

Comment: as far as your question about the screw head, use a screw with a wide head, so that it does not pull through the mounting hole ... use a washer if necessary

Comment: yeah, so with the above comment you made me realise that the square can be taken off the rail, so that it can be screwed, and then click the rail back on to it directly on the window. that was my main confusion in fact.

Comment: so if you wish, you can add that answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: from what you say, your question does not ask what you actually wanted to know ... that makes it an unclear question

Comment: yep, I can see that now

Comment: Does *somebody* know their feet are now on the interwebs ... ? ;)

Comment: If the blinds are custom made, then go to the company that made them and ask them for screws. Generally, one pays more than enough for custom made products for them to throw some appropriate mounting screws into the box.

Answer (score 2):

If you're screwing straight into PVC window frames, you want large self-drillers & a variable torque drill driver that won't demolish the threads by over-tightening. You can't put self-drillers in without a drill, you can't get the speed required. You only need a thread depth that reaches through your fastener &  will fully penetrate the PVC with its thread [not the drill tip], which also saves hitting anything behind.
This is not going to be the most secure fastening ever designed - your strength limit is the PVC frame & pull-out strength on the screws. Many attach points recommended.

[image]

Alternatively, wood screws or self-tappers with a pilot hole [much more effort for very similar reward].

Strongest would be into brickwork above the window frame entirely. Plugs & screws.